# Conflict with two docker containers in different directories

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Maybe somebody had such specific problem... There are two web applications in different directories, both in docker containers. Linux (centos). When I run the first application (docker-compose up -d) everything works fine. If I launch the second application from another directory, then the first one docker container launched falls. Why? The names of the containers are different, the ports forwarded in the docker are also different.

First app config docker-compose.yml

```
services:
  web:
    container_name: myapp-nginx
    image: nginx:latest
    ports:
      - "8000:80"
      - "443:443"
    volumes:
      - ./:/myapp
      - ./nginx/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
      - ./php-fpm/php-ini-overrides.ini:/etc/php/7.4/fpm/conf.d/99-overrides.ini
    links:
      - php

  php:
    build: .
    container_name: myapp-php-fpm
    image: php:7.4-fpm
    volumes:
      - ./:/myapp
      - ./logs:/myapp/logs
      - ./php-fpm/php-ini-overrides.ini:/etc/php/7.4/fpm/conf.d/99-overrides.ini
    links:
      - mysql:db

  mysql:
    image: mariadb:latest
    container_name: myapp-mysql
    volumes:
      - /opt/myapp/data:/var/lib/mysql
    env_file:
      - mysql.env
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"

  phpmyadmin:
    image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
    container_name: myapp-phpmyadmin
    environment:
      - MAX_EXECUTION_TIME=600
      - UPLOAD_LIMIT=800M
      - PMA_HOST=localhost
      - PMA_PORT=3306
      - PMA_ARBITRARY=1
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    links:
      - mysql:db
```

Second app docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'
services:
  web:
    container_name: client-nginx
    image: nginx:latest
    ports:
      - "20203:81"
    volumes:
      - ./:/myapp_client
      - ./nginx/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
      - ./php-fpm/php-ini-overrides.ini:/etc/php/7.4/fpm/conf.d/99-overrides.ini
    links:
      - php

  php:
    build: .
    container_name: client-php-fpm
    image: php:7.4-fpm
    volumes:
      - ./:/myapp_client
      - ./logs:/myapp_client/logs
      - ./php-fpm/php-ini-overrides.ini:/etc/php/7.4/fpm/conf.d/99-overrides.ini
    links:
      - mysql:db

  mysql:
    image: mariadb:latest
    container_name: client-mysql
    volumes:
      - /opt/myapp_client/data:/var/lib/mysql
    env_file:
      - mysql.env
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - "20202:3307"

  phpmyadmin:
    image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
    container_name: client-phpmyadmin
    environment:
      - MAX_EXECUTION_TIME=600
      - UPLOAD_LIMIT=800M
      - PMA_HOST=localhost
      - PMA_PORT=3307
      - PMA_ARBITRARY=1
    ports:
      - "20204:82"
    links:
      - mysql:db
```

Comment: Perhaps you can share a [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your config (i.e: docker-compose files) or give us some more information to work with

Comment: Are the names of the directories the same?  Do you have something like `app1/docker/docker-compose.yml` and `app2/docker/docker-compose.yml`?

Comment: What is the error, please share last lines of the log of the containers that falls.